# Django sort queryset according to related objects

Tags: python, django, sorting

First, happy Chinese new year.

I got this problem and I am searching for a good way to sort queryset:

The are three entities: `Service, Order, Rating`.

A `Service` object can have many `Order` objects, an `Order` object can only have one `Rating` object.
Now, I want to rank the a `Service` according to its average `Rating`.

The most straight-forward answer will be: 
first query all `Orders` of `Service` and calculate its average `Rating`, then sort the `Service` according to average rating.

However, I am worried about the efficiency and responsiveness.

So, I am thinking that there should be an attribute in the `Service` object: `Average_Rating`. And every time a review is created, the `Average_Rating` is updated.

Is this method a good way to improve responsiveness? If so, what is the best way to implement it? Thank you.

Comment: It's better to see the code than the explanation, please post the code for your models.

Comment: although there is no code to view, I basically understand what you are talking about. In fact, I think the 'straight forward' solution is not that bad. The point is the extra calculation happens every time your want to rank your Service. And for the second solution, which is adding a new attribute, extra calculation happens every time a review is created. Furthermore, the average rating calculation is not such expensive since you would make it within one db hit plus o(n) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to denormalize, you can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/).

Assume your models are something like:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)

class Rating(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField('Order')
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can annotate and query by the average:

```
Service.objects.annotate(avg_rate=Avg('order__rating__grade')).order_by('avg_rate')
```

Comment: Hi, Eran. Thanks! It seems to work. One more question, if the relation between Rating and Order is one to many (one order has many reviews), how to apply this method?

Comment: Afaik. exactly the same

Comment: Thank you! So far it's the simplest solution I've seen.